# TypeError: instance.render is not a function After sucessful Compilation

Tags: reactjs

I'totally new to React, and trying to make simple logout button that shows '0' or '1' and this number has to be state. Terminal gives me that it compiled successfully, but i'm keep getting errors on browser.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// libraries
import $ from 'jquery';
import ApiList from '../../config/apiList.json';

//Component
import Nav from '../navigation/index';

class index extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

  }

  logout = () => {
      $.ajax({
          method: "GET",
          url: ApiList.env + ApiList.endpoint.logout,
          crossDomain: true,
          xhrFields: {
              withCredentials: true
          },
          success: data => {
              window.location = "/login";
          }
      })
  }

}

export default index;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

Please add  render() method on class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// libraries
import $ from 'jquery';
import ApiList from '../../config/apiList.json';

//Component
import Nav from '../navigation/index';

class index extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  logout = () => {
      $.ajax({
          method: "GET",
          url: ApiList.env + ApiList.endpoint.logout,
          crossDomain: true,
          xhrFields: {
              withCredentials: true
          },
          success: data => {
              window.location = "/login";
          }
      })
  }
  render(){
     return <button onClick={this.logout}>Logout</button
  }

}

export default index;
```

Answer (score 1):

Every class component in React must have render() method and render should return jsx.